# Is it OK to use Java SDK 19 with graalvm-svm-java17-windows-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final.zip in a Gloun project on a windows x64 OS?

Tags: java, gluon, graalvm

I have followed the instructions at https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_introduction and developed a Gluon - SingleViewProject using the IntelliJ IDE 2022 with Gluon Plugin installed. I selected openjdk 19 as the project SDK, and am using the Gluon GraalVM build, graalvm-svm-java17-windows-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final. The sample program runs fine and I am able to build native image (.exe) file which runs and am able to generate installable package for windows (.msi) file.

I have searched google for "problem with gluon project using java sdk 19 with gluon graalvm 17" and variations on this search but am not finding anything relavent.

Is it mistake to use openjdk 19 with graalvm-svm-java17 for ANY reason? Can I run into problems down the line by doing so?

Comment: As long as nothing critical for Gluon was changed in Java19 compared to Java17, it should be fine. Nevertheless, if you pretend to release your project as a product, I would advice not using a non-LTS version of Java to build it. Use Java 17 or wait for the next LTS (or to Java 19 to be designated as LTS) if that's the case -- would be my advice.

Comment: @Jetto Martinez Thanks for pointing out the LTS issue.  I will follow your recommendation.